# CTreeCtrl 'TVN_ITEMCHANGED ' not getting fired when item checkbox is clicked in windows xp?

Tags: mfc, windows-xp

I am having a tree control and the Tree control consists of a Root node 
and that root node consists of one child node inturn this child node consists of 3 nodes.
This treecontrol is on a propertypage and in this after I click on any of the checkbox I am 
enabling the wizard buttons.And in the event handler to `TVN_ITEMCHANGED` I enabled the sheet 
buttons.

When I had run my application and after checking a node of treecontrol I am not able to enable the 
sheet buttons.I had seen the code is absolutely fine where I am checking the check state of the node
and enabling the sheet buttons.I started debugging my code and first it was `NM_CLICK` is getting fired 
and then I was expecting the `TVN_ITEMCHANGED` event to get fired but it is not at all getting fired.

I have no idea why this event is not getting fired,and the environment I am using is `WindowsXP`.

I had run my application on `windows7` ,`windows 8`,`windows vista`.There it is working as expected,but in XP only 
I figured out this behaviour.

Can anyone please help me to get this problem resolved.

Answer (score 7):

According to [MSKB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/261289) you don't get a specific notification when the checkbox is clicked.

> On a TreeView control with the TVS_CHECKBOXES style, there is no
>   notification that the checked state of the item has been changed.
>   There is also no notification that indicates that the state of the
>   item has changed. However, you can determine that the user has clicked
>   the state icon of the item and act upon that.

Quoting from that article:

> When the user clicks the check box of a TreeView item, an NM_CLICK
>   notification is sent to the parent window. When this occurs, the
>   TVM_HITTEST message returns TVHT_ONITEMSTATEICON. The TreeView control
>   uses this same condition to toggle the state of the check box.
>   Unfortunately, the TreeView control toggles the state after the
>   NM_CLICK notification is sent.
>
> You can post a user-defined message to the same window that is
>   processing the NM_CLICK notification, and treat this user-defined
>   message as a notification that the checked state has changed.
>   Following is sample code that illustrates how this can be
>   accomplished:

With the associated example code:

```
#define UM_CHECKSTATECHANGE (WM_USER + 100)

case WM_NOTIFY:
{
   LPNMHDR lpnmh = (LPNMHDR) lParam;
   TVHITTESTINFO ht = {0};

   if(lpnmh->code  == NM_CLICK) && (lpnmh->idFrom == IDC_MYTREE))
   {
      DWORD dwpos = GetMessagePos();

      // include <windowsx.h> and <windows.h> header files
      ht.pt.x = GET_X_LPARAM(dwpos);
      ht.pt.y = GET_Y_LPARAM(dwpos);
      MapWindowPoints(HWND_DESKTOP, lpnmh->hwndFrom, &ht.pt, 1);

      TreeView_HitTest(lpnmh->hwndFrom, &ht);

      if(TVHT_ONITEMSTATEICON & ht.flags)
      {

         PostMessage(hWnd, UM_CHECKSTATECHANGE, 0, (LPARAM)ht.hItem);
      }
   }
}
break;

case UM_CHECKSTATECHANGE:
   {
   HTREEITEM   hItemChanged = (HTREEITEM)lParam;
   /*
   Retrieve the new checked state of the item and handle the notification.
   */ 
   }
break;
```

Comment: `WM_USER+100` is reserved for use by the author of a window class. Since you didn't implement the TreeView control, don't use them. Custom messages start at `WM_APP`.

Comment: @IInspectable ,So what should I do and how to do.Can you please help me.

Comment: Roger's post should be set as the answer. Anyway I cast my vote.